# Unable to boot Ubuntu from USB in old system

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, live-usb

I recently got an old PC from my college Linux group. I tried to live boot Ubuntu 16.04, but I could not do that. Tried it with both 64 bit and 32 bit versions, but no good.

- The USB drive gets detected as a Mass Storage device during the POST.
- When using 64 bit live usb, it shows a smiley and H
- When using 32 bit live usb, looks like it does not recognize the USB drive as bootable, and just says "**DISK BOOT FAILURE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER**"
- Moreover, in BIOS, there is neither the option to select the device from which to boot. So I just prioritized the boot order to Removable Drives -> USB ZIP.
- In my PC, I am able to live boot both of them.

Boot priority screen
[image: Boot Priority set to USB ZIP]
Available boot devices as Removable device:
[image: Available removable devices for Boot priority]

## PC Spec

From the POST Screen:

- ASUS A7V600-X Motherboard
- AMD Athlon XP 3000+ Processor
- 1 GB RAM
- NVIDIA GeForce4 MX 440 AGP8X VGA

Comment: Please tell us as much as possible about the computer: Brand name and model or motherboard, CPU, RAM (how much), graphics processor. - Does the USB drive boot in another computer?

Comment: How old is this computer ?

Comment: @sudodus Added the specs. Yes, the usb live boot works in my system, for both 32 bit and 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Exactly how old is the computer?  It's entirely possible the system won't support the USB drive as a bootable device - there are systems old enough for that.

Comment: @ThomasWard The BIOS time resets to 2002. So must be old as that.

Comment: @Kenpachi I have systems from 2004 that don't accept USBs as boot devices.  If your BIOS doesn't let you select boot order amongst the devices, it probably has a "boot menu" where you can override that, somewhere, but if it's 2002, it might not have USB boot support, possibly.

Comment: @ThomasWard Not sure whether USB ZIP means USB Pendrive or not. I have updated the question with BIOS Boot Priority Screen, with list of options available

Answer (score 0):

A computer with an AMD Athlon XP 3000+ processor is quite old. It belongs to the K7 family, which creates problems with some modern software. Introduction date 10-Feb-03, so maybe sold 2003 o4 2004. It should work with Lubuntu, but not with standard Ubuntu. It might be hard to boot it from USB (USB ZIP is probably a ZIP-drive, a special kind of 'super floppy disk'). You might be able to boot it with Plop and chainload to USB. But I think you have best chances to boot from a CD drive.

You can try with

```
lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
```

and

```
lubuntu-14.04.1-alternate-i386.iso
```

which are small enough to squeeze into a CD disk.

You can also try with some special linux distros for old computers, for example **Wary Puppy**. See this link for more details about old computers,

[Old hardware brought back to life](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2130640)